# Getting information from a user-provided account list into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Users will paste an account list in this format, with a username, a colon, and a password on each line.

```
    username1:password1
    username2:password2
    username3:password3
    username4:password4
```

What is the **best** way to separate each line and then each part in Javascript? I'd really like it to be as simple as accounts[1].username or accounts[3].password to retrieve data. Thanks!

Comment: Before asking for the best solution, have you tried to get it to work in *any* way?

Comment: disagree. It's better to ask best practice if you have time (especially if you new in that area), than made some working solution and than try fix it.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html). You need to parse that information and form the json objects array. Example from previous link

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
    ]
};

myJSONObject.bindings[0].method    // "newURI"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope passwords are not allowed to have colons in them or they're encoded somehow prior to you having to split on a colon.  :)

```
// for each account string, split it on a colon.
var accountString = 'username1:password1';
var accountInfo = accountString.split(':');

// initialize an accounts array.
var accounts = [];

// add a new item (in JSON format here) to the accounts array.
accounts.push({username : accountInfo[0], password : accountInfo[1] });
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `:` with `,password:` for each line

insert `{username:` at beginning of each line

insert `},` at end of line

trim last comma ","

concat with `{accounts:[` + modified string + `]}`

this gives you a json string, eval it as json